# Using MuleStudio to create/deploy user jar (not a flow)

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a class I want to deploy to Mule as a user jar. It contains a class that extends AbstractTransformer.

I created a simple Java project in Mule, and added my class.  It has errors because AbstractTransformer isn't resolved.

In the project properties, Java Build Path, Libraries tab, I clicked "Add Library" and selected the "Mule Runtime" library.  A popup appears saying this is "already on Studio classpath. Nothing to do. Click 'Finish'".

But when I expand that library, none of the Mule jars appear, and the mule AbstractTransformer is still not resolved.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of a [bug](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/STUDIO-2694) affecting studio. It has been recently fixed and it will be part of Studio 3.4.

HTH